# sklearn.decomposition.PCA explained_variance_ratio_ attribute does not exist

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

When trying to identify the variance explained by the first two columns of my dataset using the `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute of `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'explained_variance_ratio_'
```

My code (condensed):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
df = df.dropna()
df_transform = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(df_transform)
var_exp = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

When the last line is executed, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'explained_variance_ratio_'
```

I am using sklearn version 0.20.0

**Edit**

After examining the attributes of `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, I see that the attribute does indeed not exist (as shown in the image).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is untested, but I believe the error is occurring because you're calling explained variance on the `fit_transform` object, as opposed to simply just the results of `fit`.

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
df = df.dropna()
df_transform = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(df_transform)
new_df = pca.transform(df_transform)
var_exp = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Comment: This version worked for me.

Comment: This answer also fixed my issue. You can verify that you have setup your environment correctly by running some in memory generated example code (rather than your real data) and if that works, the problem is not your environment and probably something along the lines of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do not need to pass through your parameters through the PCA algorithm again (essentially what it looks like you are doing is the PCA twice). Just add the `.explained_variance_ratio_` to the end of the variable that you assigned the PCA to.

For example try:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(df_transform)
```

Setting instead your `var_exp =` to:

```
var_exp = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not solve the problem. Examining the attributes of pca using pdb.set_trace(), I see the attribute explained_variance_ratio_ does not exist... Any idea how/why this is?

Comment: Yep, as the edit above shows, the issue is not in the implementation of the method, but in sklearn.decomposition.PCA itself. I tried reinstalling everything in a virtual environment to try and solve the issue, but to no avail... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version then. The attribute explained_variance_ratio_ exists the latest version to this date, sklearn 1.2.1.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/84570)